# Run eclipse as normal user in ubuntu

Tags: linux, eclipse

I am currently using Eclipse 3.4 on an Ubuntu 9.04 machine. I can only run eclipse as root and not as a normal user.
The error I get when I use it as a normal user is :

```
/home/user/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/247/data/listener_1925729951/artifacts.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.save(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.save(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:833)

......
```

The only two plugins installed are  :
1) Subversion 1.6
2) WASCE 2.1 Adapter (Application Server)

However it works fine when ran as root

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check the permissions of the plugin files in the eclipse folder (wherever you installed it). Perhaps your user account doesn't have access.

Comment: Thank you. I had installed Subversion as root and that caused the problem.